# The difference between the volume of a set and the measure of a set?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

For a set $S$, we can evaluate its volume $\operatorname{Vol}(S)$ or its measure $\mu(S)$ based on a measure $\mu$.

My question is: In what condition can $\operatorname{Vol}(S)$ and $\mu(S)$ have the same meaning? I'm writing a paper (in computer science) and want to substitute $c \operatorname{Vol}(S)$ for $\int_{r \in S} c \mu(dr)$, where $c$ is a constant and $\mu$ is any one measure. Is the substituting right? or rigorous?

Comment: What do you mean by "Vol(S)" precisely?

Comment: I mean the cardinality, the length, the area or the volume of $S$ etc.

Comment: Lebesgue measure is usually taken to be the definition of volume, but sometimes Jordan measure is used.

Comment: In my paper, I want to substitute $c \operatorname{Vol}(S)$ for $\int_{r \in S} c \mu(dr)$, where $c$ is a constant and $\mu$ is any on measure. Is the substituting right? or rigorous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It completely depends on your definition of $\mathrm{Vol}$, since there is no standard definition. Most people would define it as $\int_Sd\mu$, so it's probably fine. If you want to be absolutely rigorous, though, just go ahead and include this definition of $\mathrm{Vol}$ at the beginning of your paper.